# grid.arrange with different geom

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment

I have the following `data.table`:

```
dput(debt_dt_rate)
```

structure(list(Date = structure(c(16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 
16556, 16587, 16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 
16832, 16861, 16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 
17106, 17136, 17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 
17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 
17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140), class = "Date"), 
    Total_Debt = c(16172660.3118, 24748954.9334, 23715774.9026, 
    22544915.6204, 20583505.96055, 19421496.9112, 18318361.2343, 
    17262811.6254, 16212190.2747, 15295490.48442, 14384236.50862, 
    13477977.2242, 12746335.1577, 12037756.1513, 11333824.934, 
    10635020.45834, 9260367.4557, 8783398.3268, 8312347.9855, 
    7844790.8162, 7380479.8311, 6923488.47, 6469970.2799, 6019742.9158, 
    5572998.8237, 5133697.9165, 4697791.5315, 3489736.7093, 3064608.30743, 
    2642979.3009, 2286415.98173, 1932701.98031, 1581687.70227, 
    1249068.0842, 1067287.38269, 891533.1488, 794507.4624, 707837.1244, 
    623061.3247, 540349.6035, 459360.2506, 381820.06611, 306118.81, 
    274015.62, 243173.29, 216503.66, 191173.67, 167105.64, 144363.66, 
    126123.44, 107968.85, 89954.1, 71885.78, 54007.14, 36203.98, 
    18496.74, 870.97), Rate_Mean = c(0.0110326585539761, 0.011139704241154, 
    0.0111045496197387, 0.0110799499979222, 0.0110200792552765, 
    0.0109863297513123, 0.0109469058035287, 0.0108992365197961, 
    0.0108447251211066, 0.0108248555800818, 0.0108016128809191, 
    0.0107744736783219, 0.0107920692771933, 0.0108095814095823, 
    0.0108281568258678, 0.0108478293086854, 0.0107745577785952, 
    0.0107768206207373, 0.0107769026221056, 0.0107755046611141, 
    0.0107725226565144, 0.0107675612519358, 0.0107601178954451, 
    0.0107497957604701, 0.0107357400329724, 0.0107178851092619, 
    0.0106943643928971, 0.0103882090387314, 0.0102945851834854, 
    0.0101671606455755, 0.00999913829559724, 0.00976470573348041, 
    0.00942093915460458, 0.00897332454625535, 0.00878256033052308, 
    0.00850164591444073, 0.00839145872734851, 0.00820781529019079, 
    0.00796867039948853, 0.0076497930780956, 0.00721357444443409, 
    0.00658777083030085, 0.0056487661966019, 0.00564702816594543, 
    0.00563125903878259, 0.00570209428501116, 0.00577458636487441, 
    0.00584775920390838, 0.00592, 0.00592, 0.00592, 0.00592, 
    0.00592, 0.00592, 0.00592, 0.00592, 0.00592), SD = c(0.00314422907412743, 
    0.00406659363726963, 0.00406149664508202, 0.00406149664508202, 
    0.00406149664508202, 0.00412099822831836, 0.00418682167404248, 
    0.00418682167404248, 0.00409890501673759, 0.00409890501673759, 
    0.00409890501673759, 0.00404788594847631, 0.00411927400844535, 
    0.00411927400844535, 0.00411927400844535, 0.00427007694656846, 
    0.00447495257356909, 0.00447495257356909, 0.00447495257356909, 
    0.00447495257356909, 0.004563532402646, 0.004563532402646, 
    0.004563532402646, 0.004563532402646, 0.00463723035649911, 
    0.00463723035649911, 0.00463723035649911, 0.00469749071139946, 
    0.00469749071139946, 0.0048184714095252, 0.0048184714095252, 
    0.0048184714095252, 0.00442812854438814, 0.00413812865104072, 
    0.00413812865104072, 0.00387755320635398, 0.0042538274848789, 
    0.0042538274848789, 0.0042538274848789, 0.0042538274848789, 
    0.00453503518617237, 0.00453503518617237, 0.00370776899977794, 
    0.00370776899977794, 0.00153795717809914, 0.00153795717809914, 
    0.00153795717809914, 0.00147265774638916, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -57L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .Names = c("Date", "Total_Debt", "Rate_Mean", 
"SD"), .internal.selfref = )

and I would like to use `grid.arrange` to produce one graph above using `geom_area` and below use `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar` with the same x-axis.

Here is the code:

```
rect1<- data.frame (xmin=as.Date("2015-02-01"), xmax=as.Date("2015-07-01"),     ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)
rect2 <- data.frame (xmin=as.Date("2015-07-01"), xmax=as.Date("2015-12-01"), ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)


g4 <- ggplot() + geom_bar(data=debt_dt_rate, aes(x=Date, y=Rate_Mean),stat="identity",alpha = 5/10) + geom_errorbar(aes(x=Date,ymax=Rate_Mean + SD,
                              ymin=Rate_Mean - SD),
                          position=position_dodge(1),
                          data=debt_dt_rate) + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("3 months"),labels=date_format("%b-%Y")) +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +  scale_y_continuous("Interest Rate (%)",label=percent) + geom_rect(data=rect1,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),alpha=0.1,fill="blue")+ geom_rect(data=rect2,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),alpha=0.1,fill="red")+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-1,0.5,0.5,0.5), "lines"))

g5 <- ggplot() + geom_area(data=debt_dt_rate, aes(Date, Total_Debt),alpha = 5/10) + scale_y_continuous("Total Debt (R$)",label=dollar) +scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("3 months")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +geom_rect(data=rect1,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),alpha=0.1,fill="blue")+geom_rect(data=rect2,aes(xmin=xmin,xmax=xmax,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax),alpha=0.1,fill="red")+ theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    plot.title=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,-1,0.5), "lines"))


gp1<- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g4))
gp2<- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g5))
maxWidth = unit.pmax(gp1$widths[2:3], gp2$widths[2:3])
gp1$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
gp2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
grid.arrange(gp2, gp1)
```

When I suppress from `g5 chunk` the `theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,-1,0.5), "lines"))` the x-axis become aligned in both the upper and the lower graph. However there is an inconvenient space between them which I would like to get rid of.

I appreciate your thoughts on this matter.

Thx!

Comment: To align the graphs you should set `limits` for the `x-axis`. On both graphs you can add something like `scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("3 months"), labels=date_format("%b-%Y"), limits = c(as.Date("2014-12-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31")))`

Comment: Great solution @shadow! Kudos!